# visual studio 2005 compile website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

How can I compile website (not web project) using visual studio 2005?
Whenever I compile, those dll for the website app_code is not found in my website bin folder, but instead, in a temporary dll folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files).

Is there anyway for me to have the compiled dll in the bin folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[you can use publish web site feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

In the publish Properties, check `"Use fixed naming and single page assemblies".`

Comment: So, will this able to generate the dll file in the bin file instead in the temporary folder? Is it possible to copy and paste those dll files in temporary folder to the bin files?

Comment: Yes, why don't you try your self and check?

Comment: yupe, it works like a magic. Also found that, if there are errors in the code, it will still say publish succeed but the folder is empty (which I experienced previously).  Took quite sometime to debug the error..